# How to check inside Unknown Child Value, Firebase Database?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOjJH.png)

I have the database structure shown in the image,
and I am using the following reference to retrieve the child values.

```html
private fun readNotificationComments() {
        val notifRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Notifications")
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
                .child("Comments")
                .child(/*unknown child*/)

    notifRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                (notificationList as ArrayList<Notification>).clear()

                for(snapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
                {
                    val notification = snapshot.getValue(Notification::class.java)
                    (notificationList as ArrayList<Notification>).add(notification!!)
                }
                Collections.reverse(notificationList);
               notificationAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                refresh = true
                swipe_refresh_comments.isRefreshing = false
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
        
    })
    }
```

Now my problem is that the value "-MYxVs5l5bmRA-rf9PSt" is unknown and created randomly, how to make changes so that it the function looks for data past that unknown child value?

This is the model class

```kotlin
class Notification
{

    private var userid: String = ""
    private var text: String = ""
    private var postid: String = ""
    private var ispost: Boolean = false


    constructor()

    constructor(userid: String, text: String, postid: String, ispost: Boolean) {
        this.userid = userid
        this.text = text
        this.postid = postid
        this.ispost = ispost
    }

    fun getUserId(): String
    {
        return userid
    }
    fun setUserId(userid: String)
    {
        this.userid = userid
    }
    fun getPostId(): String
    {
        return postid
    }
    fun setPostId()
    {
        this.postid = postid
    }
    fun getText(): String
    {
        return text
    }
    fun setText(text: String)
    {
        this.text = text
    }
    fun getIsPost(): Boolean
    {
        return ispost
    }
    fun setIsPost(ispost: Boolean)
    {
        this.ispost = ispost
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Okay Ill make the changes

Comment: What is the purpose of having two consecutive pushed IDs, one after another?

Comment: @AlexMamo The top one actually is the postid and below will be a collection of all comments under that post. So one pushed ID's will have multiple sub childs having all comments.

Comment: @AlexMamo and I want to display all comments of all posts into a recyclerview hence the problem

Comment: Meaning that everything it's under the "Comments" node, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir and comments of each post are separated by their own sub node, I am doing this so that when a user delete a posts it will also delete all the notifications associated with it, the deletion is working properly but I need to read all of them into a recyclerview of all comments combined yet, that's my problem